# Why subset cut decimal part?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Hi this is a sample of *data.frame / list* with two columns containing X and Y. And my problem is when I call **subset** it will cut decimal part. Can you help me figure why?

(row.names | X | Y)

```
> var
...    
9150    4246838.57   5785639.07
9152    4462019.15   5756344.11
9153    4671745.07   5791092.53
9154    4825699.93   5767058.37
9155    4935126.99   5839357.55
> typeof(var)
[1] "list"
> var = subset(var, Y>10980116 & X>3217133)
...
6569  15163607 11323070
6572  15102381 11079465
6573  16462260 11272569
6577  19028175 11095784
```

It's the same when I use:

```
> var = var[var$Y>10980116 & var$X>3217133,]
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a subsetting issue, it's a formatting/presentation issue.  You're in the first circle of Burns's [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) ("[i]f you are using R and you think you’re in hell, this is a map for you"):

> another aspect of virtuous pagan beliefs—what is printed is all
>   that there is

If we just print this bit of the data frame exactly as entered, we "lose" digits.

```
> df <- read.table(text="
       4246838.57   5785639.07
       4462019.15   5756344.11
       4671745.07   5791092.53
       4825699.93   5767058.37
       4935126.99   5839357.55",
  header=FALSE)
> df
##        V1      V2
## 1 4246839 5785639
## 2 4462019 5756344
## 3 4671745 5791093
## 4 4825700 5767058
## 5 4935127 5839358
```

Tell R you want to see more precision:

```
> print(df,digits=10)
##           V1         V2
## 1 4246838.57 5785639.07
## 2 4462019.15 5756344.11
## 3 4671745.07 5791092.53
## 4 4825699.93 5767058.37
## 5 4935126.99 5839357.55
```

Or you can set `options(digits=10)` (the default is 7).